# is it possible to return a view from another controller and pass it into a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller

I want to do something, maybe it s not best practice or logical but here is the scenario:

```
public firstController (){ 
    public IActionResult someview(variable){ 
          var result = anotherController().anotherView(variable);
          return PartialView("_somePartial" , result);
  } }
```

Maybe, there would be a better solution for this but i am newbie, already sorry for not so good question and already thanks for answer or answers

Comment: search for `asp core render view to string`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks for reminder that was a typo ;

Comment: @abdusco I am checking, thanks

Comment: A simpler solution is to reference the view you're rendering inside `_somePartial`, like rendering another partial.